# Several short questions on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1. Let $A, B$ be square matrices, let $U$ be the kernel of $Ax=0$, $W$ be the kernel of $Bx=0$, $V$ be the kernel of $(AB)x=0$.
>
>    - $dimV=0\Rightarrow dimU=0$ or $dimW=0$
> 2. Let $T:V\to W$ a linear map, therefore:
>
>    - If $dim(W)<dim(V)$ then $T$ isn't an injection.
>    - If $ker(T)=\{0\}$ then $dim(W)=dim(V)$
> 3. Let $Ax=b$, $A$ is a matrix over the real numbers of the order $m\times n$.
>
>    - If for every two solutions $x_1, x_2$ of the system, also $x_1 + x_2$ is a solution, then it be that $b=0$.

These questions are from a true or false sheet, these are only the true ones that I didn't understand. Please explain why they're true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

(1) For example, do you know that $\;U=\{0\}\iff \;A\;$ is a bijection $\;\iff \det A\neq 0\;$ ? And you know that $\;\det(AB)=\det A\cdot\det B\;$ ?

(2) If $\;T:V\to W\;$ is an injective linear map then $\;\dim V=\dim T(V)\;$

The second point here is false. Use the above for a counterexample.

(3) This should be almost trivial:

$$Ax_i=b\;,\;i=1,2\;,\;\text{and we're given}\;A(x_1+x_2)=b . \text{ But}\;A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2\,,\,\text{so}\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

1. This one is true with "and". If $\dim V=0$ this means that $AB$ is injective, and so invertible (as we are dealing with matrices). Then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible, and then $\dim U=\dim W=0$.
2. If $T$ is an injection, then its image has dimension equal to that of its domain. In other words, if $T$ is injective then $\dim W\geq\dim V$.
3. You have $Ax_1=b$, $Ax_2=b$. If $x_1+x_2$ is a solution it means that $b=A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2=2b$. So $b=0$.

Comment: About 3, why does $b$ necessarily have to be zero ?

Comment: Because $b=2b$. If you subtract $b$ from both sides, you get $0=b$.